# Help with sql query using case and group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case

I have a DB Table with a date and a field called posneg, the value is either 'pos', 'neu' or 'neg'.

I need a result set where the posneg values are added and then grouped by date. Like this

```
2010-10-03    5   (on that date it could be 12 pos, 5 neu and 7 neg)
2010-10-04    -3  (on that date maybe 10 pos, 2 neu and 13 neg)
...and so on
```

Basically the neu doesn't matter, as you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  date,
  posneg = SUM(
    CASE posneg
      WHEN 'pos' THEN 1
      WHEN 'neg' THEN -1
      ELSE 0
    END
  )
FROM atable
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Andriy M's answer worked well. Since it was the first one, I tried that first... I rewrote it to:
SELECT dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, date)) as d,  posneg = SUM(CASE posneg WHEN 'pos' THEN 1 WHEN 'neg' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Table GROUP BY dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, date)) order by d
So thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT date, SUM(IF(posneg='pos',1,IF(posneg='neg',-1,0))) as total
FROM table GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with tab as(

select cast('12/12/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'neg' as posneg 
union all
select cast('12/12/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'pos' as posneg 
union all
select cast('12/12/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'pos' as posneg 
union all
select cast('12/12/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'pos' as posneg 
union all
select cast('12/15/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'neg' as posneg 
union all
select cast('12/15/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'neg' as posneg 
union all
select cast('12/15/2010' as smalldatetime) as dt, 'pos' as posneg
)

select dt,
sum(case when posneg='pos' then 1
         when posneg='neg' then -1
         else 0 end) as total
         from tab
         group by dt
```